# In Python how to obtain a partial view of a dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Is it possible to get a partial view of a `dict` in Python analogous of pandas `df.tail()/df.head()`. Say you have a very long `dict`, and you just want to check some of the elements (the beginning, the end, etc) of the `dict`. Something like:

```
dict.head(3)  # To see the first 3 elements of the dictionary.

{[1,2], [2, 3], [3, 4]}
```

Thanks

Comment: "the beginning" and "the end" have no meaning with Python dictionaries because their order is arbitrary.

Comment: What do you mean by "first three elements"? A `dict` has no inherent sense of key ordering.

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing dictionaries and lists?

Comment: I meant, the first three elements that would come up if you call the dict on your console.....Sometimes you do that, and if the dict is very long, you get a ton of data that clutters all your console space.

Comment: Again: `dict`s have no inherent order.

Comment: @hernanavella: But you can't control or predict what three elements those will be.  If you mean you want to just show an arbitrary subset of the dict elements, you can do that, but you won't know ahead of time exactly which elements you'll be seeing.

Comment: @iCodez I get that, but what if you just want to take a quick look at how the dict looks.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok. How do you show say 3 or 4 dict elements ?

Comment: I want to know how  this is a dictionary  `{[1,2], [2, 3], [3, 4]}`

Comment: This is not a strange desire at all — I often have the situation where some calculation has returned a dictionary and I want to look inside it to make sure that it has the correct data and I haven't made a mistake. The order doesn't matter, I just want to see a sample of the data. This doesn't seem like it should be hard. I think the best answer is `list(my_dict.items())[:5]`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Kinda strange desire, but you can get that by using this

```
from itertools import islice

# Python 2.x
dict(islice(mydict.iteritems(), 0, 2))

# Python 3.x
dict(islice(mydict.items(), 0, 2))
```

or for short dictionaries

```
# Python 2.x
dict(mydict.items()[0:2])

# Python 3.x
dict(list(mydict.items())[0:2])
```

Comment: perhaps `dict(sorted(mydict.items()[:3])`

Comment: well if the order does matter, yes. But as far as i understand author don't need that. He just wants elements that would be printed at the beginning when printing dictionary and that is exactly what it is

Comment: `.items()` is an iterator, convert it to a list first, or it ll raise an error when sliced.

Comment: @user5061: No, OP specified Python 2.7.

Comment: # user 5061
In python2 items returns list.
In python3 you can use islice to slice your iterator.

Comment: Not so strange, if you are using Jupiter notebook, a long dictionary will be shown completely, or rather it could crash the session. There is a missing functionality there, like for data frames, it only shows the top and bottom for longer data frames.

Answer (score 17):

Edit:

in Python 3.x:
Without using libraries it's possible to do it this way. Use method:

> .items()

which returns a list of dictionary keys with values.

It's necessary to convert it to a list otherwise an error will occur  *'my_dict' object is not subscriptable*. Then convert it to the dictionary. Now it's ready to slice with square brackets.

```
dict(list(my_dict.items())[:3])
```

Comment: Could you give some context to your answer so it is useful for others?

Comment: Is it more understandable now?

Comment: works fine for my use-case where I need mock-data of a huge dict to do testing.

Answer (score 8):

```
import itertools 
def glance(d):
    return dict(itertools.islice(d.iteritems(), 3))

>>> x = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12}
>>> glance(x)
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

However:

```
>>> x['a'] = 2
>>> glance(x)
{1: 2, 3: 4, u'a': 2}
```

Notice that inserting a new element changed what the "first" three elements were in an unpredictable way.  This is what people mean when they tell you dicts aren't ordered.  You can get three elements if you want, but you can't know which three they'll be.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is 3 years old but here a pythonic version (maybe simpler than the above methods) for `Python 3.*`:

```
[print(v) for i, v in enumerate(my_dict.items()) if i < n]
```

It will print the first `n` elements of the dictionary `my_dict`

Comment: This only works if your keys are typically incrementing integers. What if you have negatives, large numbers, strings, or dates?

Comment: @Wassadamo why would this not work with arbitrary keys?

Comment: You're right. Enumerate indexes are used instead of the keys

Answer (score 5):

one-up-ing @Neb's solution with Python 3 dict comprehension:

```
{k: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(my_dict.items()) if i < n}
```

It returns a dict rather than printouts

Answer (score 2):

If keys are someway sortable, you can do this:

```
head = dict([(key, myDict[key]) for key in sorted(myDict.keys())[:3]])
```

Or perhaps:

```
head = dict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda: x:x[0])[:3])
```

Where `x[0]` is the key of each key/value pair.

Answer (score 2):

For those who would rather solve this problem with `pandas` dataframes. Just stuff your dictionary `mydict` into a dataframe, rotate it, and get the first few rows:

```
pd.DataFrame(mydict, index=[0]).T.head()
```

`0  hi0
1  hi1
2  hi2
3  hi3
4  hi4`

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

I've only toyed around at best with other Python implementations (eg PyPy, IronPython, etc), so I don't know for certain if this is the case in all Python implementations, but the general idea of a dict/hashmap/hash/etc is that the keys are unordered.

That being said, you can use an [`OrderedDict` from the `collections` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). `OrderedDict`s remember the order of the keys as you entered them.

Comment: He states in his comments that he already knows that. He just needs a small sample of dict contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
list(reverse_word_index.items())[:10]
```

Change the number from 10 to however many items of the dictionary `reverse_word_index` you want to preview

Answer (score 0):

A quick and short solution can be this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"a": [1,2], "b": [2, 3], "c": [3, 4]}

pd.Series(d).head()

a    [1, 2]
b    [2, 3]
c    [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Pay attention that this gives you an `object` instead of a `dict`. Meaning after `head = pd.Series(d).head()`, this will not work: `for name,group in head`... but this will: `for name in head.keys(): # \n #
    group = head[name]`

Answer (score 0):

This gives back a dictionary:

```
dict(list(my_dictname.items())[0:n])
```

If you just want to have a glance of your dict, then just do:

```
list(freqs.items())[0:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of items in a dictionary is preserved in Python 3.7+, so this question makes sense.

To get a dictionary with only 10 items from the start you can use `pandas`:

```py
d = {"a": [1,2], "b": [2, 3], "c": [3, 4]}

import pandas as pd
result = pd.Series(d).head(10).to_dict()
print(result)
```

This will produce a new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3}
for i in list(d.items())[:2]:
     print('{}:{}'.format(d[i][0], d[i][1]))

a:1
b:2
```

Comment: 1. needs `''` around `a, b, c`. 2. for first two elements, it's `[:2]`. 3. `i` is a tuple. 4. why not an f-string? 5. `i, d[i]` isn't right, you'd need `i[0], i[1]`. But `for k, v… print(f"{k}: {v}")` would be better.

Comment: (@JackDeeth about #4, question is flagged python 2.7, a f-string wouldn't be right.) Was this code tried ? As was already mentionned, .items() returns a tuple. You either want .keys() instead or need to change the print statement...