# How to split json into multiple files per document

Tags: json

I have a large json file that contains thousands of documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "document1",
        "fields": [ ... ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "document2",
        "fields": [ ... ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I'd like to split this json file so that each json file contains a single document, and name them accordingly:

```
document1.json, document2.json, ...
```

For example, `document1.json` will contain:

```
{
    "_id": "document1",
    "fields": [ ... ]
}
```

I have no knowledge of jq API, and I'm struggling to find an answer (I've find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744361/split-a-json-file-into-separate-files), but slightly different :( )

Comment: Are you familiar with any programming languages such as PHP, etc?

Comment: @kojow7 I'm not familiar with the languages relevant to JavaScript and web applications. My domain is based on Python, MATLAB and C++.

Comment: I have added a pseudo-code answer for you below. If you do end up trying out some language-specific code and still cannot get it to work, add it to your answer above, and then leave me a comment letting me know that your question has changed.

Comment: If the file is small enough to put in memory, you can first convert to JSON Lines format and then split using https://www.convertcsv.com/text-split.htm

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Python solution to your problem.

> Don't forget to change the `in_file_path` to the location of your big JSON file.

```
import json

in_file_path='path/to/file.json' # Change me!

with open(in_file_path,'r') as in_json_file:

    # Read the file and convert it to a dictionary
    json_obj_list = json.load(in_json_file)

    for json_obj in json_obj_list:
        filename=json_obj['_id']+'.json'

        with open(filename, 'w') as out_json_file:
            # Save each obj to their respective filepath
            # with pretty formatting thanks to `indent=4`
            json.dump(json_obj, out_json_file, indent=4)
```

Side Note: I ran this in Python3, it *should* work in Python2 as well

Comment: Please comment if you have any questions about the code. :)

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. For anyone reading, if the 'key' you want for the filename is in a sub-property of the array element, use json_obj['properties']['LGA_CODE16']+'.json'

Comment: Hi Stefan, I have a requirement to split the JSON files based on rows say every 30 rows, instead of the id. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Pop it in a question with some sample data and I can have it for you in about 7 hours. Sounds like your dealing with a json array though?

Comment: @StefanJCollier you mean in a separate question?

Comment: Yeh a new stack overflow question

Comment: Hi @StefanJCollier i have asked it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688115/splitting-json-files-based-on-row-counts

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today as well, and did some research. Just want to share the resulting Python snippet that lets you also customise the length of split files (thanks to [this slicing method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704691)).

```py
import os
import json
from itertools import islice

def split_json(
    data_path,
    file_name,
    size_split=1000,
):
    """Split a big JSON file into chunks.
    data_path : str, "data_folder"
    file_name : str, "data_file" (exclude ".json")
    """
    with open(os.path.join(data_path, file_name + ".json"), "r") as f:
        whole_file = json.load(f)

    split = len(whole_file) # size_split

    for i in range(split + 1):
        with open(os.path.join(data_path, file_name + "_"+ str(split+1) + "_" + str(i+1) + ".json"), 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dict(islice(whole_file.items(), i*size_split, (i+1)*size_split)), f)
    return
```

Update: Then, when you need to combine them together again, use the following code:

```py
json_all = dict()
split = 4         # this is the 1-based actual number of splits

for i in range(1, split+1):
    with open(os.path.join("data_folder", "data_file_" + str(split) + "_" + str(i) + ".json"), 'r') as f:
        json_i = json.load(f)
        json_all.update(json_i)
```

Answer (score -2):

While it is true that the `JS` in JSON stands for JavaScript, JSON is not dependent on JavaScript or other specific programming languages. Most modern programming languages are able to read a JSON file. So what you'll need to do is the following:

1. Choose the language you are most comfortable with (i.e. Python)
2. Read the large JSON file
3. Convert the JSON file to an object specific to your programming language (step 2 and 3 may be combined depending on your language choice from step 1)
4. Loop through each object in the array
5. In your loop create a new file with the specified filename.
6. Also in your loop, save the data from that object to the file
7. Also in your loop, close the file (steps 5 to 7 may be combined depending on your language)

This is a generic algorithm dependent on the language that you choose in step 1. If you still cannot get it to work trying it out in a specific language add your language-specific code to your question above and we can help you further.