# Splitting JSON files based on row counts

Tags: python, json, csv

UPDATE:
I am converting my csv file, for example, 19-01-2018.csv with some 1000 odd rows to a json file, namely 19-01-2018.json

The requirement is that, the json files created need to be split up to 30 rows each. So, my target files will be like 19-01-2018_1.json, 19-01-2018_2.json etc.

source json looks like this:

[image]

And each of those json files created need to be further split into separate jsons with 30 rows each, since I need to ingest to Azure and there is a size constraint.

Below is the code I used to convert csv to json. I wish to further split the json's into jsons of 30 rows each.

```
for i in files:
    csvfile = open(path+i, 'r')
    jsonfile = open(output+i.split('.')[0]+'.json', 'w')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        json.dump(row, jsonfile)
        jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append each row to a list, and when the list size reaches `30`, dump it to the file.

```
for i in files:
    out_index = 0
    with open(path+i, 'r') as csvfile
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        rowlist = []
        for row in reader:
            rowlist.append(row)
            if len(rowlist) == 30:
                dump_list_to_json(rowlist, path+i, out_index)
                rowlist = []
                out_index += 1
        # dump the last batch
        if len(rowlist) > 0:
            dump_list_to_json(rowlist, path+i, out_index)

def dump_list_to_json(rowlist, csv_filename, index):
    json_filename = csv_filename.replace('.csv', '_'+index+'.csv')
    with open(json_filename, 'w') as jsonfile:
        json.dump(rowlist, jsonfile);
        jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Hi Barmar. Thanks for the code. I have attached a snap of my file. Its a time series file and is labeled like 19-01.csv. So with the code which you sent, it keeps updating the same file again and again. So 19-01.json has only the last 30 rows and not the old ones.

Comment: What do you mean by "source json"? You said that the source data is CSV, and the output is JSON.

Comment: `output+i.split('.')[0]` ignores discards the part of the filename with `i` in it.

Comment: It should be `output.split('.')[0]+i+'.json'`

Comment: yes. source is csv and out put is JSON. I convert the csv file to Json. That is working fine. Now, those Jsons which were created, they need to be split only till 30 rows. not more than that

Comment: That's what `if len(rowlist) == 30` does. Whenever you have 30 rows collected, it writes it to the file.

Comment: Is each group of 30 rows supposed to be in a different file? I thought you just wanted them as separate JSONs in the same file.

Comment: Yes. differerent file Barmar :)

Comment: Could you update the question to show what you're trying to achieve? How are all the files named related to the input files?

Comment: Updated Barmar.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I keep getting this error::  if len(rowlist) == 30:
  dump_list_to_json(rowlist, path+i, out_index)
 json.dump(rowlist, jsonfile) jsonfile.write('\n')
 rowlist = []

NameError: name 'jsonfile' is not defined

Comment: I forgot to remove the lines from the loop that were replaced by the call to `dump_list_to_json`